# Building array from xml response

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a response that I am building into an array. I have had to take certain id's from the original response to create another rest connector. The code looks like this (excuse variable names, I run out of ideas after awhile):

```
foreach ($newArray as $r=>$p){
foreach ($p as $t=>$hoop){


checksession();
$restNew2 = new RESTConnector();


$urlNew2 = "https://localhost:9630/api/users/".$p['user']."/";
$restNew2->createRequest($urlNew2,"GET", null, $_SESSION['cookies'][0]);
$restNew2->sendRequest();


$responseNew2 = $restNew2->getResponse();

$xmlNew2 = new SimpleXMLElement($responseNew2);


$newerArray = array();
foreach ($xmlNew2->children() as $newestChild){
    for($g=0, $count2 = count($xmlNew2); $g < $count2; $g++) {
    $userID = (string)$xmlNew2['id'];
    $first[] = (string)$xmlNew2->name->first;
    $last[] = (string)$xmlNew2->name->last;
$newerArray[$g]['first'] = $first[$g];

}

}
}
}
```

if I print the array it looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [first] => LightSpeed
    )
}
```

There are 18 invoices that I am trying to get usernames from but the usernames are supposed to be all different. When I print_r($first} (which is the first name of the user in the response) I get almost 2,000 array entries in which those different usernames do show up. I have been messing with this for hours and can not get it. Please help!

Comment: On an unrelated note, this type of code is why I hate PHP and won't ever choose it for any projects again, ever.

Comment: Well thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: It's not your fault. PHP's model of how it handles things like this is awful to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xmlNew2 = new SimpleXMLElement($responseNew2);
$new_array = json_decode(json_encode($xmlNew2));
```

Then loop through `$new_array`. That should be easier to work with.